# "RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration" every time i run the app. (Nothing Works)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web.py

So every time I try to run the app I get "RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration error". I am using Python 3.7 (btw I don't know how to type fancy in this so its nice to see)

I have tried changing utils.py 
`yield next(seq)` to

```
try:
    yield next(seq)
except StopIteration:
    return
```

but that didn't seem to work. I've also re installed webpy but it didn't work.

```
import web

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'Hello'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class Hello:
    def GET(self, name):
        if not name:
            name = 'World'
        return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This error pops up:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Korisnik\Desktop\Python Files\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\web\utils.py", line 526, in take
>       yield next(seq)
>   StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Korisnik/Desktop/Python Files/Web/main.py", line 6, in 
>       app = web.application(urls, globals())
>     File "C:\Users\Korisnik\Desktop\Python Files\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 62, in **init**
>       self.init_mapping(mapping)
>     File "C:\Users\Korisnik\Desktop\Python Files\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 130, in init_mapping
>       self.mapping = list(utils.group(mapping, 2))
>     File "C:\Users\Korisnik\Desktop\Python Files\Web\venv\lib\site-packages\web\utils.py", line 531, in group
>       x = list(take(seq, size))
>   RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration

Comment: did you install the experimental version?

Comment: The attempted fix you describe is exactly what you want. You say it doesn't work, but what does happen when you try it?

Comment: When i do the "fix" the same error pops up...

Answer (score 0):

[The `webpy` documentation](http://webpy.org/) says that the latest full release (0.39) only works on Python 2. There's work in progress towards supporting Python 3, but for now it's only available in development builds.

You can try installing one of those, with `pip install web.py==0.40-dev1`.

Comment: I fixed it. Was changing the yield thing in my main python 3.7 folder, instead of the current projects folder. Thanks for your answer though :)

Comment: @zhyn @Blcknght I don't see a `yield next(seq)` in `utils.py`.  Only `yield y` on line 635, `yield self._head` on line 697, `yield next(self.i)` on line 701 and `yield next()` on line 754.  Is it the last one?

Comment: @mLstudent33: I have no idea what you're referring to. The latest versions of webpy appear to support Python 3.5+ out of the box, so you shouldn't need to be rewriting their internals yourself, just get an up to date version.

Answer (score 0):

I was going into my main python folder and changing the yield thing there INSTEAD of going into the folder where my project is. The fix is changing the yield thing to the improved yield thing.